# Windows docker container with python and c++ build tools OR connect python with SQL Server without c++ build tools

Tags: sql-server, docker, visual-studio, pyodbc, build-tools

I currently use pyodbc to push and pull from a Microsoft SQL Server. Pyodbc needs the Visual Studio C++ build tools to work.

I am putting this project into a docker container as a flask app along with some other flask apps. Each app has its own container. I am using traefik as a reverse proxy.

So far my docker app has been working until I introduced pyodbc. Now I am struggling to get the c++ build tools into the container alongside python.

So there are two routes. The easier (if possible) would be to connect with the server using another module. However, I couldn't find anything.

The second is to get both python and c++ build tools into the container.

I've followed these two links with no success at all. I've of course tried variations but nothing worth showing unfortunately.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2022

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/build-tools-for-visual-studio-installed-but-not-av/1354812

Unfortunately this has to be done with windows. I am on Windows Server 2019.

I'm not looking for a complete solution from anyone because I know how specific this issue is but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: C++ build tools are only required if there isn't a pre-compiled wheel file on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/#files) for the version of Python you are using. You could either use a wheel file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) or you could use a version of Python that has wheel files available from PyPI.

Comment: @GordThompson That was huge. I've never installed directly from a wheel file. Thanks.